# Error when trying to push code to nexus maven

Tags: java, git, maven

I have found out that in order to add my code to my nexus repo I have to use `mvn deploy`
When ran I get this error:
https://hastebin.com/wikisohuni.pas
I have searhced ALL over stackoverflow and online guides, but NOTHING has worked! 
settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://192.168.0.145/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <proxies></proxies>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.modello</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>removed</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

My pom can be found at: https://github.com/PhanaticGames/PhanaticSpigotCore/blob/master/pom.xml

EDIT: I edited my settings a bit and got that error to go away, however, I now get this error: https://hastebin.com/ohukowohud.sql
However, these are what run my jar. I am making a central API for other plugins ran by these jars.

Comment: It looks like your local nexus is supposed to be a mirror for everything but isn't resolving artifacts in maven central. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302754/nexus-is-not-caching-maven-central-plugins

Comment: Not a dup. As I said, I tried everything that I could find, including that. The URL http://192.168.0.145/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.0/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom returns a 404. No idea how to fix...

Comment: However, I do have this: http://192.168.0.145/repository/maven-central/

Comment: So you've tried removing the mirror and your profiles from settings.xml and you still get the same error?

Comment: First are you really have a commercial version of Nexus running? Cause you pom file states that you are using staging repositories? Furthermore why do you have defined supplemental repositories in your pom cause you already have a settings.xml which redirects all requests to your Nexus?

Comment: No? I was just trying whatever the guies said. All the things I just read and tired